# How to make a named method parameter required Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, methods, parameters, named

```
void checkIfAllValsAreIn(
    { Map<> map,
    bool isBool,
    Function() callback}) async {...}
```

How do I make any one of these named parameters required when called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make them `@required`

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
void checkIfAllValsAreIn(
    { @required Map<> map,
    @required bool isBool,
    @required Function() callback}) async {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add in body:

```
assert(isBool != null);
```

Comment: This doesn't work, but the first answer does. Thank you.

Comment: 1. This will be a runtime check instead of a build-time one. 2. Whether an argument may be null can be independent of whether it's required. For example, you might want to require that callers always supply an argument but permit them to explicitly pass null.